# How linked two micro services spring cloud

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud

Hello i would like to know how two micro-services can communicate with each other . Exemple:

I have a authentification service and a company service. I would like to set if you want to check the list of company's first you need to be authentificate by the authentification service.

This is my repo with all the services:

https://github.com/costelmarianmereuta/communication-services.git

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

For internal API calls, you can directly hit the load balancer URL, appended with the API endpoint of the company service. Depending on your architecture you may have a separate load balancer for each microservice or a single load balancer might have multiple services running on it on different ports.